# Visual intuition for the definition of "asymptotically equivalent"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

I'm trying to intuitively grasp the following definition:

> The real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ are **asymptotically equivalent as $x \to \infty$** if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1.$$ We write this as $f \sim g$.

My question is: **how do we visually interpret this in terms of the graphs of $f$ and $g$?** Does this mean that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ get closer to each other as $x$ gets larger and larger?

My only intuition for this comes from the following example: we know that $\sin x \sim x$ as $x \to 0$ (since $\lim_{x \to 0} (\sin x)/x = 1$). And as we can see below, the graphs of $\sin x$ (the green line) and $x$ (the black line) get closer and closer as $x$ goes to $0$.

[image]

But this intuition does not seem to hold for functions *asymptotically equivalent at $\infty$*. I graphed $x^2 + x$ (black line) and $x^2$ (green line) and their graphs do not appear to be getting closer at all! In fact, it looks like there's a "gap" between the two graphs.

[image]

This leads me to believe that I'm not interpreting "asymptotically equivalent" in the right way. I've come across the idea that $f \sim g$ means that $f$ and $g$ have the "same rate of growth", but that feels very unintuitive for me. Is there are a way to *see* that in the graphs?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Basically it means the *percentage difference* between the vertical distances between points on the two graphs approaches $0.$

Comment: Draw the graph of $f/g$ and it will get closer and closer to $1$ as you move towards right in the graph. You can't ensure $f$ close to $g$. For that you need $f-g\to 0$ and not $f/g\to 1$.

Comment: By the way, I think this is an excellent question since asymptotic equivalence is a very powerful tool in maths. It can be used to give intuitive justifications to a number of theorems, and is also not too hard to turn these justifications into rigorous arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$x^2+x$ and $x^2$ *are* asymptotically equivalent, since
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2+x}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}1+\frac{1}{x}=1 \, .
$$
So it is probable that you simply didn't choose $x$ values that were large enough to make your intuitions work. For example, $x=100$ gives
$$
\frac{100^2+100}{100^2}=\frac{10100}{10000}=1.01 \, ,
$$
and you can see that they are very close to each other in relative terms. Notice the use of the word *relative* here. The example you gave helps illustrate what I mean. Let $f(x)=x^2+x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. $f(x)-g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. This means that in absolute terms, the two functions are growing apart. However, the ratio between them—what you need to multiply $x^2$ by to get $x^2+x$—is approaching $1$. This is what the notion of 'asymptotically equivalent' is trying to capture.

To visualise this, it would be better to use a logarithmic scale:

[image: Semi-log plot]

Look at $x=10$, for instance. $x^2=100$, whereas $x^2+x=110$. This discrepancy looks small when we use a logarithmic y-axis, since the gap of $10$ is small relative to how large the functions are. Or, as Paramanand Singh has suggested, we could plot $y=(x^2+x)/x^2$:
[image: f/g plot]

Comment: do you mean $g(x) =x^2$?(same in the first sentence)

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you! The distinction you drew between "absolute" vs. "relative" difference made everything click.

Comment: My follow-up question would be: how do we interpret *relative* difference using the graphs of $f$ and $g$? From the picture you posted, it looks like the graphs $f$ and $g$ are "hugging" each other; but since $f(x)-g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ so wouldn't the graphs eventually grow arbitrarily far apart? That's why I'm struggling to visually interpret the notion of "relative difference". Any tips would be appreciated :)

Comment: @chaad Imagine plotting the two graphs on a $1:1$ scale. This would be very awkward, especially for large values of $x$. It will probably get to a point where you have to scroll on your computer to go from $g$ to $f$. The amount of scrolling you have to do is proportional to the distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. This is what 'absolute difference' might mean intuitively. Then, imagine using a more reasonable scale. If both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are very big, then it seems silly to worry about the differences between them (more precisely, the distances between them are tiny relative to...

Comment: @chaad ...the size of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ themselves). This is what 'relative difference' is trying to capture. In a sense, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ *should be* hugging. This perhaps shows the deficiencies in linear scales—they don't show us the big picture. They exaggerate discrepancies, which, in a relative sense, are tiny.

Comment: @chaad NB If you look closely, then you can still see $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ moving apart in the graph. It's just that we don't consider this difference to be very important.

Comment: @chaad [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ttjc32tdzt) is a plot of $\log(x^2+x)$ versus $\log(x^2)$. (I used the base-$10$ logarithm here, but any is fine.) Because we are using a more 'reasonable' scale, the two graphs are actually coming together, not going apart. Logarithmic scales are in many ways preferable, since they don't emphasise small discrepancies like linear scales do. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Joe Wonderful! That plot of $\log(x^2 + x)$ versus $\log (x^2)$ did it for me. I agree with you that the reason "relative difference" is hard to visualize is largely because of linear scales being inadequate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @chaad I removed the old graph, since I thought it was misleading. I've replaced it with a log plot and the graph of $f/g$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117650/discussion-between-joe-and-chaad).