# Limit of sin function

Tags: calculus, limits, problem-solving

I need some help solving the following limit:

Here is how I started:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(6x)\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}{{\sin(2x)}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{6 \sin(6x)}{6x}\frac{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}{x}}{{\frac{2 \sin(2x)}{2x}}}$$

I don't know how to deal with this sqrt...

Thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{\sin 2x}}{x}$ does not exist.

Comment: Write $\sin x$ as \sin x for better formatting. You can see more at [how to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last step has an error.  The $x$ under the square root shouldn't be there.  So your next step should be

$$= \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{6}{2}\sqrt{\sin 2x} = 0.$$

Comment: You are right!! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The limit equals:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(6x)}{6x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}} \cdot 6x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 6x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{6}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{x} = 0.$$

Comment: I didn't understand what you did here, how the sqrt contains 2x?

Comment: We have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}$.

Comment: I see, so I need to multiply the whole thing with $\sqrt (2x)$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=2x\to 0^+$:

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{\sin 3y}{\sqrt{\sin y}}=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{3\sin y-4\sin^3 y}{\sqrt{\sin y}} =\lim_{y\to 0^+} 3\sqrt{\sin y}-4(\sin y)^{5/2} =0 $$

Comment: Thanks, why is the limit of $(\sin(y))^\frac{5}{2}$ is 0?

Comment: @Math4me $\sin y$ goes to zero, so $0^{\frac 52}$ will also go to zero!

Answer (score 0):

Use the asymptotic equivalence $\sin(x) \sim x$ for $ c\rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Hence you get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{6x}{\sqrt{2x}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{6\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}} =0 $$

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I do not know what asymptotic is yet.

Comment: I refer you to this threat to have a glimpse of it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959757/visual-intuition-for-the-definition-of-asymptotically-equivalent/3959790#3959790

Comment: If you learn asymptotic equivalence you can solve basically 90% of limits just in your mind, without pencil and paper! It’s terrific!

Comment: Thank you for that! :)

Comment: If $g(x) \sim h(x)$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = 0$. For the limit to $0^+$, you can get this by substituting $u = 1/x$ which gives you a limit in terms of $u$, and $\sin(1/u) \sim 1/u$ is really the same as $\sin x \sim x$ by another change of variables. Note that for the limit to exist, you need $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ to be continuous around $0^+$ (or usually $+\infty$), which in this case is true.

Comment: Exactly, just a minor typo on the limit, that should be 1 ;)