# What is the visual explanation and intuition behind the "asymptotic equivalence" and the "order of growth" (BigTheta and Tilde notations)?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, intuition

I'm trying to grasp the essence of asymptotic equivalence and the order of growth definitions and meaning, but it's already taking too much time. Let's start with the tilde notation. From Wikipedia:

$$
{
f(x) \sim g(x) \quad (as \quad x \to \infty)
}
$$

if and only if:

$$
{
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
}
$$

So, if we take the following functions as an example:

$$ \bbox[yellow]
{
f(x) = x^2 + x \cdot \log_2 x
\qquad (1)
}
$$

and
$$ \bbox[yellow]
{
g(x) = x^2
\qquad (2)
}
$$

and plot them for x=0..10:

[image: plot functions in range 0..10]

they doesn't seem identical here. But then, if we draw for x=0..10000:

[image: plot functions in range 0..10000]

they became almost identical. Clearly, it works as x approaches infinity. But why?

In contrast, if we use $g(x) = x^3$ instead, the limit will be equal to 0, which means, that this pair of functions isn't asymptotically equivalent.

But how does it work? Why functions are asymptotically identical if and only if
$
{
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
}
$ .
Why can we trust this definition? Is there a visual explanation of it?

Comment: It may be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959757/visual-intuition-for-the-definition-of-asymptotically-equivalent?rq=1

Comment: If you have any questions regarding my answer to the older post, then feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. I've just realized how similar those questions are. xD

It seems like I've grasped the essence. In my personal notes, I've even calculated values of $\frac{x^2 + x \cdot \log_2 x}{x^2}$ by taking huge values of x, as you did. So, I even can't produce a good question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk about two functions' behavior as $x \to \infty$, there are several ways to compare them.

One might be to talk about the absolute error between them $|f(x)-g(x)|$ and ask if it tends to zero. Graphically this is easy to visualize in the kind of plots you are making: the vertical gap between the graphs of $f$ and $g$ shrinks to zero as $x \to \infty$.

This is a very strong notion of "$f$ and $g$ behave the same as $x \to \infty$," since it excludes examples such as $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$.

There may be situations where you don't care about the *absolute error* but are more concerned with the *relative error* $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. This is a more relaxed notion of "$f$ and $g$ behave the same as $x \to \infty$." Note that it holds for the above example $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$.

The intuition is that if $f$ and $g$ both get large as $x \to \infty$, we are more and more willing to tolerate larger absolute errors between them, as long as these absolute errors are small relative to the value of the functions. Explicitly, note that $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1| = \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|g(x)|}$. It is ok for the absolute value $|f(x)-g(x)|$ to not shrink to zero, as long as it is small relative to $|g(x)|$. Note also that we have the implication $|f(x)-g(x)| \to 0 \implies |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1| \to 0$.

Unfortunately, I don't think it is easy to determine this from plots of $f$ and $g$. For instance my example of $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$ would be two parallel lines, which you might say becomes "almost identical" if you zoom out far enough, but you can come up with examples where a plot (which necessarily can't take $x \to \infty$) seems to show that $f$ and $g$ are "nearly identical," but don't actually satisfy $\frac{f}{g} \to 1$.

As a practical example of why relative error can be useful, suppose $f$ and $g$ are the number of minutes two algorithms need to process $x$ inputs. If $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$ they are both basically requiring one minute per input, but the first algorithm needs an extra minute, maybe for set-up time. The extra minute that the first algorithm requires is not really a big deal when $x$ is large: for example if there are a million inputs, we are not really concerned about the difference between $10^6$ minutes and $10^6 + 1$ minutes.

Big-O notation is an even further relaxation of this notion.

Comment: Thanks! The "error tolerance" makes it much easier to understand. However, why is the limit must be equal to 1 (and not 2 or 3 or 400)? Is it because we can rewrite $\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{g(x)}$ as $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1$ ?

I'm also trying to get it from Brujin "Asymptotic Analysis" but the book is very dense.

Comment: @PavelS Well if the limit isn't $1$, then the two functions differ by some factor in the limit, which you might not want in a definition of "equivalency." For instance, $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x$ differ by a factor of $2$. Note that in the even more relaxed setting of big-$O$ notation, we don't care about this factor; for this example both functions are in $O(x)$.

Comment: Thanks once again! As the follow-up, and a summary of my understanding of the problem I posted another answer. I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I don't the implication $|f(x)-g(x)| \to 0 \implies |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1| \to 0$ is true unless you're assuming $g(x) \to ∞$ but in that case why are you assuming that?

Comment: @William [You are right. More generally, this implication holds as long as $|g(x)| \ge C > 0$ for some $C$ for all large $x$.] We often use asymptotic analysis to compare rates of growth (e.g. running times of algorithms), where both $f$ and $g$ are understood to grow to infinity and we want to compare "how fast" they grow. In my answer, I stated this claim after saying "if $f$ and $g$ both get large as $x\to \infty$" to demonstrate the distinction between the two separate notions $|f-g| \to 0$ and $|f/g-1| \to 0$, but maybe I should have been clearer about my assumptions.

Comment: Ha, is that right? Also, I wasn't paying attention to your "$x \to \infty$". I was working with the more general definition that $f$ is asymptotic to $g$ on $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{±∞ \}$ iff $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f(x)-g(x))=0$. In which case, the other definition $\lim\limits_{x \to a } \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= 1$ doesn't follow. I was hoping to see if there was some way to connect the two definitions so I got all excited when I saw your "implication" but I guess, you were only comparing for $f(x), g(x) \to \infty$. I didn't read it carefully :(

Comment: @William Yes, I don't think there is a general equivalence: one can construct counterexamples for each implication.

Comment: Actually wait, not all hope is lost. The two definitions ARE equivalent if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x), g(x)$ exist (finite) and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)≠0$. When $f$ and $g$ have infinite limits, then only one side of implication is true (as you've mentioned in your answer). So there is still connection. Phrr!!

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm very grateful for the previous answer and still believe it's better than this one, I'll post it because it may add value to this question. I'm still surprised why I haven't thought about it immediately.

The main goal of the tilde notation is to show whether two functions are similar or not. What "similar" mean? Let's start with two numbers and equality. Two numbers are equal to each other if and only if their quotient is equal to 1 (let's omit division by 0). Now, a function just maps numbers from a domain to a codomain. So, we can say, that two functions are equal when each value of one function divided by each value of another function is equal to 1 at any given point in their domain. We can write it as:
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1 , \qquad x=(-\infty, \infty)
$$

But instead of telling that our functions are equal (which is pretty useless on its own), our goal is to tell whether two functions are **similar**. Now, what "similar" means? It means that a ratio of values of functions are "almost equal" to 1. How can we tell that values of two functions are "almost equal" to 1? Do we have any mathematical mechanism to answer this question?

Yes, limits. It has a strict definition, that can help us answer the question: "how close can a function can be to a specific value" with the answer: "as close as we need it to be" (in terms of sigma and epsilon notion). Let's review a definition of a limit:

$$
\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L
$$

which means: "we can set f(x) as close as we want to L by making x sufficiently close to C" (credits to KhanAcademy).

Now we can extrapolate the definition of a limit to "similar" functions. Which is:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
$$

In terms of a limit definition, it's: "we can set f(x)/g(x) as close as we want to 1 by making x sufficiently close to infinity".

Why we only care about $x \to \infty$? Because we consider not only how **"similar"** two functions are, but also their order of growth (which means at x close to $\infty$).

We can visualize it as:

[image]

where we can clearly see that the closer two "similar" functions get to infinity, the closer f(x)/g(x) became to 1 because |f(x) - g(x)| became smaller and smaller (or "not to shrink to zero as long as it is small relative to g(x)").

*Update 1: fix the incorrect statement about |f(x) - g(x)| being smaller and smaller in the last sentence by quoting from another answer (because it's not always true).*

Comment: The last sentence is not necessarily true: consider the example $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$, where $|f(x)-g(x)|=1$ does not get smaller and smaller.

Comment: Yep, it makes sense, thank you. So, it may become smaller and smaller or stay the same, but won't get bigger, right? Because it is still must satisfy the definition of the limit. As you said in your answer "It is ok for the absolute value |f(x)−g(x)| to not shrink to zero, as long as it is small relative to |g(x)|."

Comment: It can grow as well. $f(x)=x^2+x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ has $|f(x)-g(x)|=|x| \to \infty$ but $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$.

Comment: That's fantastic! I'll quote your answer to fix this statement if you don't mind (well, I kind of already did it, but if you against it, I'll remove it).